# JavaFX missing in KUbuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk, javafx

I have have Kubuntu 18.04 installed and I use the default jdk which says version 11 in the repositories but 10 when using `java -version` command.
However, I cannot run JavaFX application because it's not included in this build.

Is there a fix other than using OpenJDK 8 or oracle JDK ?